# Home made dispersion/solution with detectable >0.1μm particles

Tags: solutions, filtering

*Sorry for the possibly wrong terminology. I'm not a chemist and I'm not a native English speaker.

Please edit the question as needed. Thank you.*

Is it possible to buy or prepare a dispersion with the following properties?

- the particles should be >0.1μm in size, for example 0.11μm - 0.2μm
- there must be a way to **detect** them - even in a small amount (colour, taste, chemical reaction with something else, ...)
- it mustn't be a "glue"; it must be possible to flush them completely away with water or something else readily available
- it mustn't be a toxic or corrosive substance
- the dispersion (or components to prepare it) should be readily available (drugstore, grocery etc.)
- the total price shouldn't be higher than $20 (I know this difficult with prices different in every country - this is just a guideline)

Why do I need it?
There's a very slight chance that a [Sawyer Micro Squeeze Water Filter](https://sawyer.com/products/sawyer-micro-squeeze-water-filtration-system/) might have been exposed to a below zero temperature and might have been damaged by frozen residual water.
The manufacturer says there's no way to test the filter functionality in that case and a new filter should be bought instead. I wonder if this is really needed or there's a way to test the filter at home.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & all confirming upvotes. As stated above, I'm not a chemist and don't know how to reword the question to be acceptable for this SE site. Is it possible to move it to https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/ with the last paragraph only and the accepted answer? (This is probably the right SE site for this question.)

Comment: I think this question was ok, perhaps added additional tags would be good, but otherwise it's prompted a really good answer that addresses a common problem which non-chemists would otherwise not have thought a good solution to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to get some clay and shake it vigorously with water. Let it settle for a several hours. Test your filter with the supernatant water and collect the filtrate in a very clean glass tumbler. Colloids have an interesting property of scattering light. In a dark room, try to shine light (ordinary flashlight might work or perhaps an ordinary pointer used in presentations/offices). Be careful, never ever look at the pointer directly. Look at the filtrate at $90^o$ (right angles to the light beam), if you see a light beam travelling in water, it means that colloidal particles are seeping through the filtrate and the filter is damaged.

Read more about the Tyndall Effect https://www.sciencesource.com/archive/Tyndall-Effect-SS2423500.html or on Wikipedia before doing anything.

[image]